# Jquery Dialog: Alert when Username and Password is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

```
$('#login_dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        draggable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Login',

    buttons: {
        "Connect": function () {   
            $(document).trigger('connect', {
                jid: $('#jid').val(),
                password: $('#password').val()
            });
            $('#password').val('');
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

How to display the alert box when username and password is both empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some checking before connecting:

```
function isValidInput(jid, password) {
    // edit this function to add other validations here
    return $.trim(jid).length > 0 && $.trim(password).length > 0;
}

$('#login_dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        draggable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Login',

    buttons: {
        "Connect": function () {
            if (!isValidInput($('#jid').val(), $('#password').val()) {
                 alert('Please enter a valid input!');
                 return;
            }
            $(document).trigger('connect', {
                jid: $('#jid').val(),
                password: $('#password').val()
            });
            $('#password').val('');
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the connect custom event and the function that would hadle it...

```
$(document).on('connect',function(e))
{
    if (!$.trim(e.data.jid + e.data.password).length)
        alert('Both empty');
}
```